# Webpack LESS to CSS configuration

Tags: webpack, less

I'm trying to setup Webpack so it transforms a LESS stylesheet to CSS.

So far I could get it to parse my LESS stylesheet but my config lacks the CSS part. I get a CommonJS file but somehow the ExtractTextPlugin doesn't extract the CSS from it...

I tried various setups but so far I got the following configuration.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
// modules
  const path = require('path');
  const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
  const extractLess = new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "style.css",
      disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"
  });
  const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
  const DotenvPlugin = require('webpack-dotenv-plugin');

  var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname,  './public/dist');
  var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './assets');
  var THEME_DIR_REL = '../themes/globo';

  const config = {
      mode: 'development',
      output: {
          path: BUILD_DIR,
          filename: '[name]'
      },
      entry: {
          'bundle.min.css': [
              // APP_DIR + '/css/forms.css',
              APP_DIR + '/lib/globo/less/style.less'
          ]
      },
      resolve: {
          extensions: ['.ts', '.jsx', '.js', '.css', '.less'],
          alias: {
              'FosRouter': path.resolve('./vendor/friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle/Resources/public/js/router.js'),
              'FosRoutes': path.resolve(BUILD_DIR, 'fos_routes.js')
          },
          modules: [
              'node_modules'
          ]
      },
      module: {
          rules: [
              {
                  test: /\.js|.jsx$/,
                  exclude: /node_modules/,
                  loader: ['babel-loader']
              },
              {
                  test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
                  loader: "file-loader",
                  options: {
                      name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
                  },
              },
              {
                  test: /\.less$/,
                  use: extractLess.extract({
                      use: [{
                          loader: "css-loader",
                          options: {url: false}
                      }, {
                          loader: "less-loader"
                      }],
                      // use style-loader in development
                      fallback: "style-loader"
                  })
              },
              {
                  test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|ico|gif|svg)$/,
                  loader: "file-loader",
                  options: {
                      name: "img/[name].[ext]",
                  },
              },
              {
                  test: /\.css$/,
                  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                      fallback: "style-loader",
                      use: ['css-loader']
                  })
              }
          ]
      },
      plugins: [
          new DotenvPlugin({
              sample: './.env.dist',
              path: './.env'
          }),
          new ExtractTextPlugin(THEME_DIR_REL + "/dist/styles.css"),
          // new CopyWebpackPlugin([
          //     { from: APP_DIR + '/lib', to: '../themes', toType: 'dir' }
          // ]
          // ,{
          //     context: './public',
          //     ignore: [
          //         '*.less'
          //     ]
          // })
      ]
  };

  module.exports = config;
```